# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Cannot create the window /не удается создать окно

Tags: windows, visual-c++, windows-8

Такая проблема: еще сегодня ночью работал в студии, все было хорошо, утром проснулся, включаю - выдает эту ошибку, уже весь мозг себе вынес, и файл настроек .NET Framework восстанавливал, и все остальное - ничего не помогает.

Что делать?
Все делал - все равно, результат один.
[1] (проблема с machine.config)
[2] (запустить setup и скомандовать "Repair")

Comment: подозреваю, что ночью накатилось обновление то ли .NET, толи IExplorer (да, в студии многие диалоговые окна - это банальный html).

Answer (score 1):

Хм. Перезагрузка не помогла? Гугл предлагает кучу вариантов:

- [[1]](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/458377/cannot-create-the-window-dialog-appears-during-vs-2010-startup) (проблема с machine.config)
- [[2]](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/89fb8d50-35d2-4fbb-aaf2-468d4400d9af/visual-studio-2010-cannot-create-the-window) (запустить setup и скомандовать "Repair")

и т. п.